# Правила соединения простых предложений в составе ССП

Tags: пунктуация

Вопроса два:

1. Нужна ли запятая перед последним простым вопросительным предложением?

Но вот они, дети «индиго», приходят в школу, заканчивают ее и куда все девается?

2. Если простые предложения в составе сложносочиненного (не вопрос. не безличн.) располагаются по принципу: основа (запятая) основа (союз "и")
   основа, то нужна ли запятая перед последней основой, или принцип соединения, как при однородных членах (общих второстепенных членов тоже нет)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая не ставится в том случае, если вопросительный интонацией объединены два предложения. Если вопросительной является только вторая часть, запятая ставится.

Но вот они, дети «индиго», приходят в школу, заканчивают ее, и куда все девается?

Во втором примере действует общее правило постановки запятой перед союзом **и** в сложносочиненном предложении.